# How to find a xpath which will return all values of dropdown using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, automation

In my HTML code don't have a tag of select either for options but if select dropdown then on click its shows name of a dropdown item on HTML code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz3Oi.png)

```
     public void user_count_list_of_client_names() throws Exception {
        //Assign and Select the dropdown list element
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(drpdown));

        // driver.findElement(clientsdrpdown).click();
        WebElement wbelement = driver.findElement(drpdown);
        List < WebElement > elements = wbelement.findElements(drpdown);
        System.out.println(elements.size());

        System.out.println("Total Number of item count in dropdown list = " + elements);

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(elements.get(i).getText());
            System.out.println(elements.get(i).getAttribute("value")); //Using for loop getting one by one dropdown name using value attribute.

            elements.get(i).click();
        }
    }
```

Comment: When clicking manually on the dropdown, do you see any new ul or li tags at the bottom of the DOM?

Comment: <span class="ant-select-selection-search"><input autocomplete="off" class="ant-select-selection-search-input" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="rc_select_0_list" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="rc_select_0_list" aria-activedescendant="rc_select_0_list_13" readonly="" value="" id="rc_select_0" style="opacity: 0;" aria-expanded="false"></span>

Comment: <span class="ant-select-selection-item">test-build</span>

Comment: i got response like this  test-build is one of list item name which is showing on manual click

Comment: @Naveen otherwise i am not able to see any ul or li tag

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the HTML code. It is too difficult to read code in a comment. Please also do not post images of code. Copy and paste the code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

So, your dropdown field xpath can be like

```
//input[contains(@class, 'selection-search-input')]
```

Click that first and then you can build XPATH for dropdown values using [Contains](https://devhints.io/xpath) class like

```
//*[contains(@class, 'selection-search')]//*[contains(@class, 'selection-item')]
```

Comment: drpdown=By.xpath("//div[@class='ant-select clients-dropdown ant-select-sm ant-select-borderless ant-select-single ant-select-show-arrow']//div[@class='ant-select-selector']");

Comment: this is my dropdown xpath its working fine on click show list but i am failed to get values from dropdown

Comment: xpath for selection values---->.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'ant-selection-search-input')]//*[contains(@class, 'ant-select-selection-item')]");